# Half a Diffuse texture comes out as white in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing

Tried rendering out my model but half of the ground renders out as white. All the texture is, is a green diffuse texture. In the Rendered View its normal but when I actually render its half green half white.

[Rendered View](https://i.gyazo.com/33b704d8c1bf1b324d13ed2f665bf186.jpg)
[image]

[Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M2GE.jpg) 
[image]
[.Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CFpL-RNmlIdQjMEBspbKKKQuM5dlJn6A/view?usp=sharing)

If anyone has any solution to this, it would really help. Thanks.

Comment: please use the tools of this site to upload images  so that they show as part of your post, and users don't have to go to a link to understand the question.

Comment: Files are gone. Question doesn't make any sense anymore. Downvoted the question, please fix.

Answer (score 2):

There was a hidden layer that was over it. I just ALt + H and it popped up